# is or has been?

Tags: present-perfect

I'd like to know if "has been" is used properly in the following dialogue. I'd use the present simple "is," but I'd like to know if "has been" is okay too.

> A: Where's Sarah now? She's not at home.

> B: She **has been** in the library.

Comment: On its own, it could mean "She was in the library earlier, but I don't know if she's still there". To give your meaning of "She is in the library", you would have to add a time phrase like "all afternoon" or "since lunchtime".

Comment: How about "She has gone to the library"?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: On its own, could "She has gone to the library" imply she went to the library earlier, but the speaker doesn't know if she's still there?

Comment: "She has left here, and her intended destination was the library."